# How to return two 256 bit YMM values in register YMM0/1 in a function (no memory involved)

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, avx, calling-convention

My goal is to return a 4x4 floating point matrix as a return value of a function without using memory.
As pointed out by the Wiki article of the "x86 calling conventions"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI it is possible to return up to two floating point values from a function using XMM0 and XMM1.

I tried this:

```
struct Mat4 // just a simple struct for testing
{
    __m256 m0, m1;
};

Mat4 Foo(__m256 m0, __m256 m1, __m256 m2, __m256 m3)
{
    return {m1, m2};
}
```

But gcc gives me this as the result:

```
mov     %rdi,%rax
vmovaps %ymm1,(%rdi)
vmovaps %ymm2,0x20(%rdi)
retq
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
vmovaps %ymm1, %ymm0
vmovaps %ymm2, %ymm1
retq
```

Is there any way to force gcc to return the whole struct `Mat4` in just YMM0 and YMM1?

Comment: x86-64 ABI only deals with SSE2 because that's what all 64 bit cpus support. Not all have AVX, hence the convention does not use `ymm` registers. Note that during inlining the compiler is not restricted by the ABI, so your code may still be efficient.

Comment: For details like this, you really want to be reading [the ABI itself](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) instead of just Wikipedia's (over)simplified summary.

Comment: In particular, from Section 3.2.3: "If the size of an object is larger than four eightbytes, or it contains unaligned fields, it has class MEMORY".  Your object is 8 eightbytes, so it is always going to be returned in memory.

Comment: @Jester Okay, but it seems like gcc with x86-64 ABI is totally fine with passing 256 bits arguments in YMM regs so I though it would be the same for returning larger values than 128 bits in YMM regs too...

Comment: That seems to be the case indeed. Interesting.

Comment: And now that I look, the example in Figure 3.6 shows a `__m256` argument being passed in a `ymm` register.  But the explanation of this case in the text is not very clear.

Comment: @Jester: Are you looking at an old version of the x86-64 SysV ABI?  Current version is 1.0.  https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI.  It's been updated for AVX (in 2009) and AVX512 (in 2015), as well as stuff like MPX.  And wording clarifications.